# how to save .svg with ggsave() the same as what I see in shiny's plotOutput

Tags: r, ggplot2, svg, shiny

I'm plotting in shiny using ggplot2.
I created a dynamically sized plotOutput to preview the plot, and eventually want to save the plot as `.svg` with ggsave().
I haven't found a suitable way to do this yet, and another problem I've found is that when I try to preview the **same size plot in px** with ggsave(), the result is **different** from what I see in plotOutput.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(uiOutput("output")),
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 5, offset = 4, style = "display: flex;",
            numericInputIcon("output_width", label = NULL, value = 800, min = 1, max = 3000, icon = "width"),
            "x",
            numericInputIcon("output_height", label = NULL, value = 600, min = 1, max = 1500, icon = "height"),
            "px"
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$output <- renderUI(plotOutput("plot", width = input$output_width, height = input$output_height))

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = displ)) +
      geom_point()
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

in shiny
[plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta9ab.png)

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = displ)) +
      geom_point()
ggsave("plot.svg", width = 800, height = 600, units = "px")
ggsave("plot.png", width = 800, height = 600, units = "px")
```

svg and png
[plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUhm3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `renderPlot` renders your plot with a default resolution of `res=72`, i.e. 72 pixels per inch, whereas `ggsave` export your plot with a resolution of `dpi=300`, i.e. 300 pixels per inch.

Hence, if you want to export your plot the same size as displayed in your Shiny app then you have to use the same resolution for both, e.g. set `dpi=72` in `ggsave`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = displ)) +
  geom_point()

ggsave("plot.png",
  width = 800, height = 600, units = "px",
  dpi = 72
)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the dpi should be set 300, as most journals require, but then the text and other elements become a mess